overrule conflicting system short cuts
I think this is more a problem of Ubuntu than of emacs, but I guess many people that use emacs on Ubuntu stumbled over this problem so it might be faster to get an answer here.
The ctrl + ; (C-;) command is already taken by the system in text fields and prints an underlined e. How can I turn off this behavior?
Here a screenshot of the problem (when I press C-;)


thank you! this answers my question.

You have to turn it off somewhere else higher in the stack. Emacs never receives the key events. Since you mention Ubuntu, it is probably a Gnome setting that you have to change. You could however be running KDE instead. You’ll have to figure that out for yourself; it’s definitely not an Emacs question.

I anticipating this issue with my question, but I thought that other people that use Gnome might stumbled over the same problem so it is much more likely to get answer here than somewhere else.
And maybe I can turn off system shortcuts within emacs or overrule them.

No, you can’t..

You can't "turn off system shortcuts within emacs or overrule them" because "Emacs never receives the key events".  I.e.: as far as Emacs is concerned nothing has happened (and so it can't possibly do anything about it).  If keys events aren't reaching Emacs, you have to deal with the problem outside of Emacs.
